# How to initialize ThreeTen Android backport in a Unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, threetenbp

I use [this library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) for storing date & time related data in my app. When the application starts, `AndroidThreeTen` is initialized first to function properly. So I want to ask how to initialize it when unit testing? E.g. I want to test using `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, etc.

My current way is like this:

```
class OverviewViewModelTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        AndroidThreeTen.init(Application())
    }

    //...
}
```

But it throws this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.threeten.bp.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:143)
    at org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:358)
    at org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:286)
    at org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.systemDefault(ZoneId.java:245)
    at org.threeten.bp.Clock.systemDefaultZone(Clock.java:137)
    at org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.now(LocalDate.java:165)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getAssets in android.content.ContextWrapper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java)
    at com.jakewharton.threetenabp.AssetsZoneRulesInitializer.initializeProviders(AssetsZoneRulesInitializer.java:22)
    at org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesInitializer.initialize(ZoneRulesInitializer.java:89)
    at org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.<clinit>(ZoneRulesProvider.java:82)
    ... 32 more
```

So how can I get this library to work in unit tests?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/issues/14

Comment: Have you tried the link from the error message? ["Method ... not mocked."](http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked)

Comment: indeed I have. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [latest comment at the GitHub issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/issues/14#issuecomment-255417720), I was able to run the Three Ten Android backport using the Robolectric library. For Kotlin users, do not use the final class. Instead, use the **open** class.

In your app's `build.gradle`, add:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    testImplementation('org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.8') {
        exclude group: 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp', module: 'threetenabp'
    }
}
```

and use this template to write tests using ThreeTenABP:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
open class DateUtilTest {

    @Test
    fun testName {
        // Write as normal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap your Android dependencies like

```
object TimeManager {
 fun init(context: Context) {AndroidThreeTen.init(context)}
 fun now() {...}
}
```

And in your test you would mock the TimeManager class
depending on which mocking framework you use, but you would do something like this

```
every {TimeManger.now()} returns System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Of course you can also use a DI approach

```
Interface TimeManager {
 fun init(context: Context)
 fun now()
}

class TimeManagerImpl : TimeManager {
     fun init(context: Context) {AndroidThreeTen.init(context)}
     fun now() {...}
}

class MockTimeManager: TimeManager {
     fun init(context: Context) {// no op}
     fun now() = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```